# AngularJS: - ngRoute and Controller http GET request causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am following the tutorials from the AngularJS site and I have hit a snag. I have tried to debug the issue myself using console.log() and alerts. It appears that something about the http request causes it to invoke the ngRoute directives in an infinite loop.

I have read a few other posts that say it is because the server is returning index.html as the response to the http request. I think this is my problem but I am not sure how to check what is being returned from my GET request.

How can I test what is being returned and prevent this infinite loop?

main.js contents

```
var coffeeBeanApp = angular.module('coffeeBeanApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'coffeeBeanControllers'
    ]);

coffeeBeanApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider.
    when('/coffee', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/coffee-list.html',
        controller: 'CoffeeListCtrl'
    }).
    when('/coffee/:slug', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/coffee-detail.html',
        controller: 'CoffeeDetailCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/coffee'
    });
}]);
```

controllers.js

```
var coffeeBeanControllers = angular.module('coffeeBeanControllers', []);

coffeeBeanControllers.controller('CoffeeListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/coffee').success(function(data){$scope.beans = data;})
});

coffeeBeanControllers.controller('CoffeeDetailCtrl',
    ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams){
        $scope.slug = $routeParams.slug;
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for better debugging:

```
$http.get('/api/coffee').then((function successCallback(response) {
       // this callback will be called asynchronously
       // when the response is available
       console.log(response); 
}, function errorCallback(response) {
       // called asynchronously if an error occurs
       // or server returns response with an error status.
       console.log(response);
});
```

or you can just put a console.log in your success callback (which is marked in red as deprecated in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
 $http.get('/api/coffee').success(function(data){console.log(data);});
```

Comment: Thanks mentat. That makes a lot of sense now having read the documentation thoroughly and spotted the deprecated 'success' method. I am still having an issue though. Even with console.log and the callbacks in place I am still getting the referenceloop which is preventing any values being logged to the console. Any idea what is causing this loop behaviour?

Comment: are you sure your http call is the issue? perhaps you can comment out and see how behaviour change. and can you share the actual error message you are getting?

Comment: mentat, you are quite right. My http call is not the issue. I moved it into a controller on its own and it works just fine. I think ngRoute is causing the issue. It seems to be calling index.html constantly nesting multiple instances of my app inside one another. Any idea what might be causing this?